# How to label markers similar to Google Maps in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, popup, marker

I am using Leaflet to load bing map tiles. The map is loading fine and I am able to put markers on the map.

But I want to know how to show label for the markers similar to the way they are shown in Google Maps i.e. a text attached to marker.

The way I want to show markers and its description on map:
  [image]

I looked into the Leaflet documentation. I found Popup and Tooltip, but they don't provide the type of view I want.

Does anybody know of some functionality in Leaflet through which I can achieve the required behaviour.

Comment: This is how it [looks](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max) in google maps. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: @kboul, I can implement that behaviour (as shared in link by you) i.e. I can create a marker and attach a popup which opens on click of marker.

Comment: But, I want to know how to put the text label on marker which is always visible. For e.g. see the image above, you can see two markers and both have their text labels ('Pickup point' & 'Road entry point') attached to them. [Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1txVrgQMLYkvYwZ5PkXKtqCJ-EHCRoeWH/view?usp=sharing) showing markers with label on google maps, this is what I want to achieve using Leaflet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that behavior you need to hide the popup content wrapper and use L.icon to place the popup content in your desired position by providing [x, y coordinates](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#icon-popupanchor)

```js
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 5);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var popup1 = L.popup({
  closeOnClick: false,
  autoClose: false
}).setContent("A pretty CSS3 popup.");

L.marker([52.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup(popup1)
  .openPopup();

var yourIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
  popupAnchor: [30, 120]
});

var customOptions = {
  'className': 'custom',
}

var popup2 = L.popup({
  closeOnClick: false,
  autoClose: false
}).setContent("A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.'");


L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {
    icon: yourIcon
  }).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup(popup2, customOptions).openPopup();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<style>
  #mapid {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .custom .leaflet-popup-close-button,
  .custom .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .custom .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
  .custom .leaflet-popup-tip {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  
  .custom .leaflet-popup-content {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @kboul for the solution. But this seems to affect other popups also. For e.g. if I want to use the native popup (as provided by leaflet) for other markers then will it be possible to do that if I change the css similar to above one.

Comment: You did not specify that to your question. I updated my answer by attaching a specific class to the custom marker and modifying the css to apply to the custom style as well only. 
There is also another marker with the default behavior which remains intact by the changes.